# Mysql get results for current month

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to get results from mysql into php results for 1 month with each day, and if row doesn't exist then display 0 to that date like below

```
2017-09-07 - 70
2017-09-10 - 0
2017-09-11 - 100
2017-09-12 - 0
2017-09-15 - 0
2017-09-20 - 0
2017-09-29 - 200
```

My table name is transactions and includes date, id, and credits fields. I tried below code I found online, but only shows 1 row, where I was trying two retrieve for two dates 1st and 26th for testing.

```
SELECT MonthDate.Date, COALESCE(SUM(`credits`), 0) FROM ( SELECT 1 AS Date UNION ALL SELECT 26) AS MonthDate LEFT JOIN transactions AS T1 ON MonthDate.Date = DAY(T1.Date) AND MONTH(T1.Date) = 9 AND YEAR(T1.Date) = 2017 WHERE MonthDate.Date <= DAY(LAST_DAY('2017-09-28'))
```

Comment: Why not just to select everything you have from mysql, and then fill empty days via PHP ? It would be much faster to implement now and easier to understand later.

Comment: Would you be able to point to an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is possible to achieve with SQL**

Let's suggest that you have table "*your_table*" with fields "*value*" and "*date*". Then SQL will look like:

```
select a.Date, IFNULL(your_table.value, 0)
from (
  select curdate() + INTERVAL 31 DAY - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
  from (
    select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
    ) as a
  cross join (
    select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
    ) as b
  cross join (
    select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
    ) as c
  ) a
left join your_table on your_table.date = a.Date
where a.Date between 'PUT_START_DATE_HERE' and 'PUT_END_DATE_HERE'
order by a.Date;
```

Comment: Thank you, it brings results limited to 7 not full month.
2017-09-01    0.00
2017-09-02    0.00
2017-09-03    0.00                                                         
2017-09-04    3.00
2017-09-05    0.00
2017-09-06    0.00
2017-09-07    0.00

Comment: That is because my script takes only dates from past, and today is 7 :) . I've updated my answer, now it should work fine with dates from past and one month in future

Comment: Sorry, How can I sum rows with same date using IFNULL rather than displaying seperately for same date. I tried COALESCE(SUM(transactions.credits) but it adds all values together rather for each dates

Comment: To have sums per date you need to add "group by a.Date" after "where", and use your COALESCE expression in Select

Comment: One last question, I was trying the function with another table but returns 0, even if exists, does coalesce need to be enabled or something to other table to show results? Thank You

Comment: @user3498121 , I'm not sure what is your problem.. Maybe post another question? And we will help you. Simply specify what is your current query, what's inside of your table and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Example as you asked, for example ( :) ) you fetched your SQL like this

```
SELECT `date`, `credits` FROM `table_name` WHERE 1
```

And get an array called **$results** like this

```
2017-09-07 => 70
2017-09-11 => 100
2017-09-29 => 200
```

So with php help, you can fill empty days like this

```
$date = (new DateTime());
$lastDay = $date->modify('last day of this month')->format('d');
$firstDay = $date->modify('first day of this month')->format('d');

for($day = 0; $day < $lastDay; $day++) {
    $date = (new DateTime())
        ->modify('first day of this month')
        ->modify('+' . $day . ' day')
        ->format('Y-m-d');

    if(empty($result[$date])) {
        $result[$date] = 0;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```